# unrecognized selector sent to instance on my own button class

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm really new on Objective-C and iOS. I'm having a problem:

I'm creating buttons dynamically and I need to store some data on the buttons to use it on the `onClick` method. I have a class for storing my data and the problem starts when trying to store that data on the button.

Here is the data class .h to be stored:

```
    @interface MenuItem : NSObject
{
    NSString *name;
    NSString *action;
    NSString *xml;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *action;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *xml;
@end
```

This class does not have any method.

Here is my button class:

```
    @interface MyButton : UIButton
{
    MenuItem * buttonInf;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) MenuItem * buttonInf;

@end
```

I'm having a problem when putting the data into that field:

```
MyButton * button = [MyButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
button.buttonInf = buttoninf;
```

I tried doing:

```
[button setButtonInf:buttoninf]
```

and making that setter, but same result, always having:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-   [UIRoundedRectButton setButtonInf:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

and I really dont know why.

Comment: unrecognized selector sent to instance it means you are not passing the correct parameter(the data type is not matched) to the method

Comment: I guess this is just a typo but shouldn't `button.buttonInf = buttoninf` be `button.buttonInf = buttonInf`?

Comment: can you show us the MyButton initialize code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIButton/buttonWithType:) say:

> **Discussion**
>
> This method is a convenience constructor for creating button objects with specific configurations. It you subclass UIButton, *this method does not return an instance of your subclass. If you want to create an instance of a specific subclass, you must alloc/init the button directly.*

That means that the object returned by `buttonWithType:` is of type of `UIButton` (not `MyButton`) and this class do not declare the `buttonInf` property.

You will have to create your button in a different way (using `initWithFrame` for example) and then your `QuartzCore` configure the aspect of the button to looks like you want.

Using the code above I get the right button shown in the image

```
MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 20, 73, 44)];
button.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
button.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
button.layer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
[button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor blueColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

Comment: cant i just cast the UIButton returned to MyButton class?

Comment: there must be something missing compiler sais:
Property border color cannot be found in forward class object CALayer
and same for border width and corner radius

Comment: by the way, you have to #import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>